# Angular - pre-select a select option with [ngValue] [(ngModel)] being objects

Tags: angular

**Goal**

I want to pre-select an option of a select with [ngValue] and [(ngModel)] with the values being an object TypeConge:

```
{ "id": 2, "libelle": "Holidays" }
```

**First Try**

```
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="font-weight-bold" for="typeConge"> Type congé </label>
                <select class="form-control" id="typeConge" name="typeConge"  [(ngModel)]="conge.typeConge" >
                    <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
                    <option [ngValue]="typeCongeOption" *ngFor="let typeCongeOption of typeConges; trackBy: trackTypeCongeById">{{typeCongeOption.libelle}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            {{conge.typeConge| json}}
```

Problem: The select option is not preselected.

**Second Try**

```
            <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="font-weight-bold" for="typeConge"> Type congé </label>
                <select class="form-control" id="typeConge" name="typeConge" [compareWith] = 'customCompareTypeConge' [(ngModel)]="conge.typeConge" >
                    <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
                    <option [ngValue]="typeCongeOption" *ngFor="let typeCongeOption of typeConges; trackBy: trackTypeCongeById">{{typeCongeOption.libelle}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            {{conge.typeConge| json}}
```

...

```
customCompareTypeConge(tc1: TypeConge, tc2: TypeConge){
        return tc1.id == tc2.id;
    }
```

Problem: In the console I find: Cannot read property 'id' of null

**EDIT**

[Link to stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpr3sq)

**EDIT 2**

A full explanation of this issue can be found at [this adress](https://www.romaniancoder.com/angular-4-custom-comparison-function-select-comparewith/).

Could you help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [(ngModel)]="conge.typeConge.id" [ngValue]="typeCongeOption.id"?

Comment: I just tried. It's not working. In any case, I would prefer to directly get the object through the select.

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz of the problem statement?

Comment: Do you set the initial value like this: `this.conge.typeConge = this.typeConges[0]`? Or `this.conge.typeConge = null` if you want to select the first option.

Comment: @ConnorsFan No. The initial value come from a request to a server. So the this.conge.typeConge contain the object typeConge { "id": 2, "libelle": "Holidays" } for example.

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar I've never done this but I can try.

Comment: The initial value must be one of the items in the list. If it is another object with the same property values, it will not match the item in the list.

Comment: [This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqm5yw) shows how you can set the initial value, and keep working with entire objects in your template. In order for two objects to be equal, they must be the same object. Two separate objects with the same properties and same values are not equal. They are like two cars of the same model and same color: they look the same, but they are not the same car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused on how the relationship between ngModel and ngValue work to default the select. It has to be a 1:1 explicit comparison between the ngModel value and the ngValue.

You appear to be using `typeConges` to define your options in your loop with `typeCongeOption` as the option value which is a complete index item, and then using `conge.typeConge` to define your ngModel... there has to be a 1 === 1 comparison between these two, you cannot compare complete index items to a value and expect a match.

Please review this stackblitz example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13wnyq?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand it completely. It's not a 1 === 1 comparison since my typeCongeOption is a TypeConge object and that my conge.typeConge is also a TypeConge object?

Comment: Your example is interesting. But conge in my case is not just an id. It is an object containing another object of class TypeConge. My problem is that I need to display it but once selected I need to retrieve it as an object too.

Comment: Do a console.log(typeCongeOption === conge.typeConge) does is log true?

Comment: There has to be an explicit match for it to work, if you provide a stackblitz example I am sure others or myself can provide recommendations on how to achieve what you need while making it work... but what you need does not change that it needs to be an explicit match unfortunately.

Comment: The stackblitz link is in my edit in my principal post.

Comment: Please refresh my stackblitz link and review, this will show the explicit comparison that I am referring to and that conge.typeConge === typeCongeOption evaluates as false. the ngModel and ngValue comparison has to result to true for it to work.

Comment: I see what you mean but I don't get how a object TypeConge can't match another object TypeConge. Indeed, if I test {{conge.typeConge === typeConges[0]}} it is evaluated to false even though {{conge.typeConge | json }} return { "id": 1, "libelle": "typeConge 1" } and {{typeConges[0] | json }} return { "id": 1, "libelle": "typeConge 1" }

Comment: Still, your solution is working for my purpose thanks. However, I retrieve only the correct id. I would have prefer to retrieve the entire object. And as I said in the precedent comment, I don't get how the equality of two equivalent object return false... ^^' There is something I'm missing to fully understand this.

Comment: Note:   {{typeCongeOption | json }} placed into the select also return  { "id": 1, "libelle": "typeConge 1" }.

Comment: Please refresh my stackblitz url, because I am using [(ngModel)]="conge.typeConge.id" the id is being changed in conge on selection change automatically... so you just need to update this.conge.typeConge.libelle  to match the new id via the setSelectedValue() method.